# How to insert an image in a canvas item?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a game project for school, which look like this :  In-game aspect

[image: In-game aspect]

I have created these colored polygons like this :

```
ship = can.create_polygon(410,650,450,600,490,650 , fill= 'red' , outline='black')

ennemies = can.create_rectangle(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, fill='green')
```

So now i want to fill **them** with my own image. Is that possible ? And how ?

Comment: Have you read through the documentation on the canvas? Adding images is a documented feature.

Comment: Yes, and i didn't find what i want : i would like to fill a `can.create_rectangle` with an image.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.constants import *
except ImportError:  # Python 2.x
    import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkconstants import *

# Create the canvas, size in pixels.
canvas = tk.Canvas(width=300, height=200, bg='black')

# Pack the canvas into the Frame.
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

# Load the .gif image file.
gif1 = tk.PhotoImage(file='small_globe.gif')

# Put gif image on canvas.
# Pic's upper-left corner (NW) on the canvas is at x=50 y=10.
canvas.create_image(50, 10, image=gif1, anchor=NW)

# Run it...
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what i want to do : i want to insert an image in the `canvas.create_rectangle`, not in the canvas.

Comment: @Milky_Way: you can't insert an image in a rectangle.  You can certainly put a rectangle and an image on the canvas in such a way that the rectangle surrounds the image. Regardless, the first step is to use `create_image` as shown in this answer.

Comment: Milky_Way: You're right, I misunderstood. Since images are rectangular, you don't really need to put them into a rectangle. If you need to resize them, you can use the `PIL` module's `tkinter`-compatible [`PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) class instead of a `tkinter.PhotoImage`. The later can also be used to read and display image files in formats that `tkinter` doesn't directly support.

Comment: It cost me quite a while to get that gif1 shall be either global var or some other way made sure it was not GC-ed