# I am getting a weird error when i am creating an image on a tkinter canvas

Tags: image, tkinter, python-3.7, tkinter-canvas

I keep getting this error when creating an image on a Tkinter canvas.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\my\user\folder\Documents\main.py", line 123, in <module>
    exec(gamecmdss)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\my\folder\main.py", line 66, in STANDARD_createimage
    gamestuff["parts"][id]["realid"] = gamecanvas.create_rectangle(coords, image=img, tags=[imgtype, "Pinecone image obj"])
  File "C:\my\user\folder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2501, in create_rectangle
    return self._create('rectangle', args, kw)
  File "C:\my\user\folder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # coordinates: expected 0 or 4, got 2
```

Here is the function that throws the error:

```
def STANDARD_createimage(id, xpos, ypos, file, imgtype=imgtype_graphic):
    global gamecanvas
    global gamewindow
    global gamestuff
    gamewindow.config(cursor="@thinking.cur")
    coords = xpos, ypos
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file=file)
    if not imgtype in imgtypes:
        print(f"Unknown image type '{imgtype}', defaulting to imgtype_graphic")
        imgtype = imgtype_graphic
    gamestuff["parts"][id] = {}
    gamestuff["parts"][id]["realid"] = gamecanvas.create_rectangle(coords, image=img, tags=[imgtype, "Pinecone image obj"]) #here is the problem
    gamewindow.config(cursor="@default.cur")
    showinfo()
```

And this is the code I keep running:

```
STANDARD_createimage("image", 50, 50, "C:/my/user/folder/Documents/exampleimage.png");
```

Comment: You are using `gamecanvas.create_rectangle` instead of `gamecanvas.create_image`.

Comment: j_4321 thanks, I should have checked my code better

Comment: Should I add as answer to mark Q as solved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an image in a canvas item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009527/how-to-insert-an-image-in-a-canvas-item)

Comment: @CoolCloud no, this has already been answered and should be marked duplicate