# Is there an way to show more than 2 images using the PIL or label function in tkinter python? Abd I need it to be capable with Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

So im trying to make an RPG-like game with Tkinter. But I can't add more than one image without it saying that 'pyimage2' doesn't exist. Here's a sample code of what I mean,

```
import PIL
import os
import tkinter

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 600, height = 500)
canvas.create_text(300, 50, text = "I have no idea what to put here :I", 20)
Btn = Button(root, text = "Some button")
aImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(("images/aimage.png")))
anotherImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(("images/anotherimage.png")))
label = Label(image = aImage, anotherImage)
label.pack()
```

If someone could help me, that would be a pleasure (Note: I'm also trying to get the Student badge)

Comment: If you're going to use Labels, you would need to have a separate Label for each image.  Only a Canvas can hold more than one image at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert an image in a canvas item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009527/how-to-insert-an-image-in-a-canvas-item)

Comment: See [ask] and [mre]. Your code are full of errors. Start with an empty TK application, add a canvas widget and add an image to the canvas. You don't need a label widget.

Comment: **"'pyimage2' doesn't exist"* error is caused by multiple instances of `Tk()` mostly. The posted code will not raise such error.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an way to show more than 2 images using the PIL or label?

The `TKinter` merely allowed a single image per widget.

To add more images, then an extra `TKinter` widget, such as `Label`, `Canvas`, etc.

Snippet for `Label`:

Screenshot for `tk.Label`:

[image]

Snippet for `tk.Canvas`:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

aImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(("p1.png")))
anotherImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(("p2.png")))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width =350, height = 200)
canvas.create_text(300, 10, text = "I have no idea what to put here :I") 
  
canvas.create_image(50, 80, image=aImage, anchor=tk.NW)
canvas.create_image(200, 80, image=anotherImage, anchor=tk.NW)

Btn = tk.Button(root, text = "Some button")

canvas.pack() 
Btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot for `Canvas`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As already been said in comments, you can’t put two images into one label directly. And it is obvious, as program has no idea of how it should put them(row by row, diagonally or in any other ways).

Instead, I would create a main Label, then put two images in separate labels and make them children of the main label. Then somehow pack, place or grid them in the main label. Simple code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')
main_label = tk.Label(bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="blue")

house = tk.PhotoImage(file="small-house-icon.png")
tree = tk.PhotoImage(file="small-tree-icon.png")

house_l = tk.Label(master=main_label, image=house)
tree_l = tk.Label(master=main_label, image=tree)

# example arrangement of them
house_l.grid()
tree_l.grid(row=1, column=1)

# put the main label
main_label.place(x=100, y=100)
root.mainloop()
```

result:
[image]

Comment: What about this one canvas.create_text?

Comment: OP wanted to use this ImageTk.PhotoImage

Comment: @toyotaSupra I just wrote a simple code example around the idea I've posted. If OP wants, he can add all of this by himself. I could use ImageTk, it would still work the same way.