# how to i show a random image from a list or folder on tkinter and have a user input the name of it

Tags: python, tkinter, game-development

basically im trying to create a flag guessing game but im having problems with showing the images onto the certain levels. when someone clicks a certain level i want a random flag to show and the user to guess the name. but ive tried a few things and none work so far idk what im doing wrong or how to call the images.

the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, Canvas, NW
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Flags Guessing Game")
window.geometry("600x500")
bg = '#d9b9e2'
bg1 = '#b9e2df'
bg2 = '#e2b9d0'
bg3 = '#dbe2b9'
window.configure(background=bg)


def level_pick():
  ebtn=tk.Button(window,font=('Times', 30), command=easy_level)
  ebtn["bg"] = "#b6d6ff"
  ebtn["justify"] = "center"
  ebtn["text"] = "Easy"
  ebtn.place(x=10,y=170,width=282,height=145)

  mbtn=tk.Button(window,font=('Times', 30), command=medium_level)
  mbtn["bg"] = "#f9ffa8"
  mbtn["justify"] = "center"
  mbtn["text"] = "Medium"
  mbtn.place(x=310,y=170,width=277,height=145)

  hbtn=tk.Button(window,font=('Times', 30), command=hard_level)
  hbtn["bg"] = "#ffb3fc"
  hbtn["justify"] = "center"
  hbtn["text"] = "Hard"
  hbtn.place(x=150,y=330,width=282,height=145)
  
  diflbl=tk.Label(window,font=('Times', 20),bg=bg)
  diflbl["text"] = "Choose a difficulty:"
  diflbl["justify"] = "center"
  diflbl.place(x=160,y=100)

  titlelbl=tk.Label(window,font=('Times', 25),bg=bg)
  titlelbl["text"] = "Flag Guessing Game"
  titlelbl["justify"] = "center"
  titlelbl.place(x=110,y=40)


def easy_level():
  new = Toplevel(window)
  new.title("Easy Mode")
  new.configure(background=bg1)
  new.geometry("600x500")
  
  ans=tk.Entry(new,font=('Times', 25))
  ans["justify"] = "center"
  ans["borderwidth"] = "1px"
  ans.place(x=90,y=270,width=414,height=188)

  rules1=tk.Label(new, font=('Times', 20),bg=bg1)
  rules1["text"] = "Enter Country Name Here:"
  rules1["justify"] = "center"
  rules1.place(x=110,y=230)
  
  
  #easyimg = ["flags/canada.jpg","flags/spain.jpg","flags/mexico.jpg"]

  # show random image
  path="flags"
  files=os.listdir(path)
  d=random.choice(files)
  os.system(d)

def medium_level():
  new = Toplevel(window)
  new.title("Medium Mode")
  new.configure(background=bg2)
  new.geometry("600x500")
  
  ans=tk.Entry(new,font=('Times', 25))
  ans["justify"] = "center"
  ans["borderwidth"] = "1px"
  ans.place(x=90,y=270,width=414,height=188)

  rules2=tk.Label(new, font=('Times', 20),bg=bg2)
  rules2["text"] = "Enter Country Name Here:"
  rules2["justify"] = "center"
  rules2.place(x=110,y=230)

def hard_level():
  new = Toplevel(window)
  new.title("Hard Mode")
  new.configure(background=bg3)
  new.geometry("600x500")
  
  ans=tk.Entry(new,font=('Times', 25))
  ans["justify"] = "center"
  ans["borderwidth"] = "1px"
  ans.place(x=90,y=270,width=414,height=188)

  rules3=tk.Label(new, font=('Times', 20),bg=bg3)
  rules3["text"] = "Enter Country Name Here:"
  rules3["justify"] = "center"
  rules3.place(x=110,y=230)

level_pick()
tk.mainloop()
```

this is one of the things i tried:

```
  path="flags"
  files=os.listdir(path)
  d=random.choice(files)
  os.system(d)
```

Comment: Do some research on how to use `Pillow` module to show image using a tkinter label.

Comment: _"none work"_ is a useless statement. What does that mean? Does the program crash? Does it show the wrong image? The right image in the wrong place or the wrong size? Something else?

Comment: Did the `Pillow` example work for you?  Note that you won't need the `os` module or `path` if you use this approach, as long as your .py file is in the same folder as the image-containing folder

Comment: yes it did tysm!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple demonstration* showing the basics of getting and displaying a random image with `tkinter` and `Pillow`.  For the example to run correctly, the .py file should be in a folder at the same level as another folder named "FlagPics."  The "FlagPics" folder should contain 3 images: "FirstFlag.png," "SecondFlag.png," and "ThirdFlag.png."  These images can be anything: just rename them as above, or change the image names in the code to match your images' actual names.

The list `pics` contains references to the 3 images in the "FlagPics" folder, created using the `Pillow` methods documented here: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-photoimage/. The picture which is initially displayed when you run the .py file will be randomly chosen from the `pics` list, and every time the user clicks the button, a new random picture will be selected from the same list.

Note that the image is displayed by the `tkinter` `Label` widget, since you set the `Label`'s `image` property to an instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage`.  Other `tkinter` widgets can also display images - examples include the `Button` and `Canvas` widgets (related question here: [How to insert an image in a canvas item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009527/how-to-insert-an-image-in-a-canvas-item)).

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from random import randint

window = tk.Tk()
window['width'] = 400
window['height'] = 400

pics = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("FlagPics/FirstFlag.png")),
        ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("FlagPics/SecondFlag.png")),
        ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("FlagPics/ThirdFlag.png"))]

def rerandomize(label):
    label['image'] = pics[randint(0, 2)]

flagLabel = tk.Label(master=window, image=pics[randint(0, 2)])
flagLabel.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.25, relheight=0.5, relwidth=0.5)

rerandomizeButton = tk.Button(window, text="Rerandomize", command = lambda: rerandomize(flagLabel))
rerandomizeButton.place(relx=0.35, rely=0.85, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.3)

window.mainloop()
```

Now that you have your random images displayed, you may also be interested in how to resize them: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-resize-image-in-python-tkinter/

*Full credit goes to user acw1668 for the idea - I only constructed a runnable example.

Comment: this worked so tysm!

Comment: i was also wondering how would i be able to have each image only show once? when i randomize it, it randomizes but shows repeats of each image

Comment: @jjk I'm not sure about the context you mean, within this example or in your original program?  If you're referring to this example, you can ensure each image only shows once by removing its reference from the `pics` list after it's shown the first time.  Don't forget to also change the upper bound in the call to `randint`, so you don't get out of bounds errors!  As matter of fact, I really should have used `randint(0, len(pics))` instead of hardcoding the upper bound `2` :)